# Vim repeat N times visual feedback

Tags: vim, repeat

I find myself in the situation of repeating some action in Vim (via `<n>action`) a lot of times. And a lot of times I manage to mistype a number. Because Vim doesn't show the numbers I type in, I find out about my mistake only after i run the command. So, I want a way to show the numbers while I type them in. Is it possible and what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:set showcmd` the numbers will appear in the bottom right hand corner. From `:h showcmd`

```
                                     'showcmd' 'sc' 'noshowcmd' 'nosc'
'showcmd' 'sc'          boolean (Vim default: on, off for Unix, Vi default:
                                 off)
                        global
                        {not in Vi}
                        {not available when compiled without the
                        +cmdline_info feature}
        Show (partial) command in the last line of the screen.  Set this
        option off if your terminal is slow.
        In Visual mode the size of the selected area is shown:
        - When selecting characters within a line, the number of characters.
          If the number of bytes is different it is also displayed: "2-6"
          means two characters and six bytes.
        - When selecting more than one line, the number of lines.
        - When selecting a block, the size in screen characters:
          {lines}x{columns}.
        NOTE: This option is set to the Vi default value when 'compatible' is
        set and to the Vim default value when 'compatible' is reset.
```

Comment: In gvim and command line vim, you have to look far to the right, but the numbers are displayed. Great answer.